# Looking for an array values inside another array keys

Tags: php, loops

I am looking for your help on this question:
How can I check if `$expInterior` values exists inside `$suppEstateInterior` keys, if the value is equal to key, I need to show the input field with the attribute **checked**, if not, leave **without** the attribute **checked**.

I am having duplicated results 5 times.

```
<?php

    $suppEstateInterior = [
    'fr' => ['Suite parentale', 'Interphone', 'Visiophone', 'Internet', 'Cheminée', 'Cuisine équipé', 'Cuisine américaine', 'Salon marocain', 'Salon européen']
    ];

    $expInterior = [1, 3, 5, 13, 18];

    $loadData = '';

    $setEstateInterior   = $suppEstateInterior['fr'];


    foreach($setEstateInterior as $ki => $interior):


        foreach($expInterior as $vk):
            if($vk == $ki):
            $loadData       .= $vk.'--'.$ki.' <input caption="yes" type="checkbox" checked name="suppInterior[]" value="'.$ki.'">';
    else:
        $loadData       .= '<input caption="no" type="checkbox" name="suppInterior[]" value="'.$ki.'">';

    endif;
    $loadData       .= $interior.'<br>';


    endforeach;

    endforeach;


    echo $loadData;
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you format your codes please

Comment: @Dlk: How can I do that?

Comment: How to use the array_diff_key  in my code?

Comment: Compare the keys of two arrays, and return the matches:   `$result = array_intersect_key($expInterior,$suppEstateInterior);
print_r($result);` copy paste this will return matches keys in two arrays. No need array_diff sorry .

Comment: I found this: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => 13 [4] => 18 )`, then what should I do?

Comment: See this tutorials for array_intersect, array_intersect_key and array_intersect_assoc https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-array_intersect_key-function/amp/ compares your both arrays you can see in my previous comment I added your both arrays.

Comment: I used array_intersect_key, then instead of using a second foreach, then I used in_array, thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you solved! I can upvote 1 of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array as a check, pulling out the inner loop and if/else:

```
<?php
$suppEstateInterior = [
'fr' => ['Suite parentale', 'Interphone', 'Visiophone', 'Internet', 'Cheminée', 'Cuisine équipé', 'Cuisine américaine', 'Salon marocain', 'Salon européen']
];

$expInterior = [1, 3, 5, 13, 18];
$loadData = '';
foreach($suppEstateInterior['fr'] as $ki => $interior):
    $in_exptInterior = in_array($ki, $expInterior);
    $caption = $in_exptInterior ? 'yes' : 'no';
    $checked = $in_exptInterior ? 'checked' : '';
    $loadData .= '<input caption="'.$caption.'" type="checkbox" '. $checked .' name="suppInterior[]" value="'.$ki.'">';
    $loadData .= $interior.'<br>';
endforeach;

echo $loadData;
```